# direct negation of concur

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm wondering what the direct opposite of "concur" is. For example, disagree is the direct negation of agree. Is there such a word?

Thanks!

Comment: Since _concur_ means _agree_, the antonym is _disagree_. That's what my thesaurus lists.

Comment: I've certainly heard "nonconcur" on numerous occasions.  And [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonconcur) lists it as going back to 1732.

Comment: _Dissent from_ vs _concur with_, where each preposition has a statement or judgement as object. This is a legal term; US Supreme Court decisions, for instance, may be concurring opinions (voting for the majority) or dissenting opinions (voting for the minority). Dissenting opinions often become majority opinions after some years.

Comment: A me-too comment for **dissent**.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a few examples of usage of the word [*disconcur*](https://www.google.com/search?q=disconcur&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22disconcur%22), but very few, and I couldn't find it in any of the dictionaries (MW, LDOCE, Macmillan, TFD, CDO and ODO).

So, I guess **differ**, maybe **oppose**, and **disagree** (as Barmar suggested) would have to suffise.

Answer (score 0):

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/concur) lists the antonym as **disagree**.

Others have stated *nonconcur* and *disconcur*. I did an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nonconcur%2C%20disconcur&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnonconcur%3B%2Cc0) search. Disconcur wasn't found and nonconcur gave very low results, suggesting it's extremely uncommon to use it.

I'd go with **disagree** if I were you. **Dissent**, as John Lawler suggested, also works if you don't mind sounding too formal.